# Multicolumn and row table

Tags: tables

I am a beginner in Latex and I have searched through the internet but can't find a code that I can use to create the table below. Anyone know and easier way to go about it.

[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Have you tried anything so far - could you give us some code? If not, start with the [`tabular`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) environment and the [`multirow`](https://ctan.org/pkg/multirow?lang=en) package.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two MWEs you can start work with.

In example 1, which I recommend, I have used caption, booktabs and no vertical line.

Example 2, is a copy of your example. However, I have used fixed width columns to ensure that the six columns in the middle are approximately of the same width.

**Example 1 – booktabs rules**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[bf, font=bf]{caption}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.0em}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small
\caption{Some key infant indicators in sub-Saharan Africa and other EHO regions}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}wl{3cm}*{6}{wc{1.3cm}}c}

\toprule
\bfseries Country &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Neonatal mortality rate*} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Infant mortality rate*}   &
 \bfseries Low birthweight \\
\midrule
& 2009 & 2012 & 2016 & 2009 & 2012 & 2016 & 2007—2016\\
\midrule
\bfseries Malawi & 30   & 24   & 23 & 69 & 46 & 42 & 12 \\
Zambai           & 29   & 29   & 23 & 86 & 46 & 42 & 11 \\
Zimbabwe         & 30.5 & 27.8 & 22 & 58 & 48 & 38 & 11 \\
Botswana         & 22   & 29   & 26 & 43 & 41 & 33 & 13 \\
Kenya            & 27   & 27   & 23 & 55 & 49 & 36 &  8 \\
\midrule
\bfseries
WHO region       &      &      &    &    &    &    &    \\
African          & 36   & 32   & 28 & 80 & 63 & 53 & 14 \\
America          &  9   &  8   &  4 & 15 & 13 &  5 &  8 \\
Europe           &  7   &  6   &  2 & 12 & 10 &  3 &  7 \\
Asia             & 31   & 27   & 28 & 45 & 39 & 39 & 30 \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\small \emph{Source} Malawi data ans World Bank Development Indicators (2015)}\\\addlinespace[-1ex]
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\footnotesize \emph{Note: *per 1000 live births }}\\

\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 – Word-like**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[bf, font=bf, hang]{caption}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.3em}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\caption{Some key infant indicators in sub-Saharan Africa and other EHO regions}

 \begin{tabular}{wl{2.4cm}|*{6}{wc{1.3cm}|}wc{2cm}}
\hline
\bfseries Country & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bfseries Neonatal mortality rate*} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bfseries Infant mortality rate*} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Low birthweight} \\
\hline
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{2009} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2012} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2016} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{2009} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2012} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2016}
& 2007-2016\\
\hline
\bfseries Malawi & 30   & 24   & 23 & 69 & 46 & 42 & 12 \\\hline
Zambai           & 29   & 29   & 23 & 86 & 46 & 42 & 11 \\\hline
Zimbabwe         & 30.5 & 27.8 & 22 & 58 & 48 & 38 & 11 \\\hline
Botswana         & 22   & 29   & 26 & 43 & 41 & 33 & 13 \\\hline
Kenya            & 27   & 27   & 23 & 55 & 49 & 36 & 8  \\
\hline
\bfseries
WHO region       &      &      &    &    &    &    &    \\
African          & 36   & 32   & 28 & 80 & 63 & 53 & 14 \\
America          &  9   &  8   &  4 & 15 & 13 & 5  &  8 \\
Europe           &  7   &  6   &  2 & 12 & 10 & 3  &  7 \\
Asia             & 31   & 27   & 28 & 45 & 39 & 39 & 30 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\small \emph{Source} Malawi data ans World Bank Development Indicators (2015)}\\\addlinespace[-1ex]
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\footnotesize \emph{Note: *per 1000 live births }}\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.tablesgenerator.com/. It is the easiest way, I think.

**Edit**:
You can paste existing table from Microsoft Excel, or import a CSV file. Then you immediately get a latex code which can be used as a starting point. For example, for the table above the following table is generated.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Some key infant indicators in sub-Saharan Africa and other WHO regions}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}lccccccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Country}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Neonatal mortality rate*}}        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Infant mortality rate*}}         & \textbf{Low birthweight} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-8} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                         & 2009        & 2012        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2016}        & 2009        & 2012        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2016}        & 2007-2016                \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Malawi}}         & \textbf{30} & \textbf{24} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{23}} & \textbf{69} & \textbf{46} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{42}} & \textbf{12}              \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Zambia}                  & 29          & 29          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{23}          & 86          & 56          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{44}          & 11                       \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Zimbabwe}                & 30.5        & 27.8        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{22}          & 58          & 48          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{38}          & 11                       \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Botswana}                & 22          & 29          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{26}          & 43          & 41          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{33}          & 13                       \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Kenya}                   & 27          & 27          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{23}          & 55          & 49          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{36}          & 8                        \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{WHO region}}                                                                                                                                                               \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{African}                 & 36          & 32          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{28}          & 80          & 63          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{53}          & 14                       \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{America}                 & 9           & 8           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4}           & 15          & 13          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5}           & 8                        \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Europe}                  & 7           & 6           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2}           & 12          & 10          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3}           & 7                        \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Asia}                    & 31          & 27          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{28}          & 45          & 39          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{39}          & 30                       \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Source: Malawi data ans World Bank Development Indicators (2015)\\ Note: *per 1000 live births\end{tabular}}                                           
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This looks interesting - I haven't seen this before. Ideally, you should give more detail in an answer as link-only answers are discouraged.